# (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away') in WSGI django

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-error-2006

I have a MySQL gone away with Django under WSGI. I found entries for this problem on stackoverflow, but nothing with Django specifically. Google does not help, except for workarounds (like polling the website every once in a while, or increasing the database timeout). Nothing definitive. Technically, Django and/or MySQLdb (I'm using the latest 1.2.3c1) should attempt a reconnect if the server hanged the connection, but this does not happen. How can I solve this issue without workarounds ?

Comment: Are the Webserver and MySQL on the same machine? If not, the closer they are the less likeley it is that a network problem will cause the server to 'go away'.

Comment: select version(); show processlist; show  variables like '%max%; Please paste output:

Comment: For anyone coming down this path in the future, here's the reasons MySQL could be returning this error:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: We can reset the connection with a single line before the problem line, see my answer in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67917637/2544762

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`show variables like 'wait_timeout';`

this is the setting will throw back the "mysql gone away" error
set it to a very large value to prevent it "gone away" 
or simple re-ping the mysql connection after certain period

Comment: well, I now changed job, so I cannot test it, but I hope it's correct :)

Answer (score 3):

Django developers gave one short answer for all questions like this in https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21597#comment:29

> - Resolution set to *wontfix*
>
> Actually this is the intended behavior after #15119. See that ticket for the rationale.
>
> If you hit this problem and don't want to understand what's going on, don't reopen this ticket, just do this:
>
> - RECOMMENDED SOLUTION: close the connection with `from django.db import connection; connection.close()` when you know that your program is going to be idle for a long time.
> - CRAPPY SOLUTION: increase wait_timeout so it's longer than the maximum idle time of your program.
>
> In this context, idle time is the time between two successive database queries.

Comment: For the first way we can also do the stuff before we do the action, see my answer in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67917637/2544762

Answer (score 1):

- You could create middleware to ping() the MySQL connection (which
  will reconnect if it timed out) before processing the view
- You could also add middleware to catch the exception, reconnect, and retry the
  view (I think I would prefer the above solution as simpler, but it should technically work and be performant assuming timeouts are rare. This also assumes a failed view has no side effects, which is a desirable property but can be difficult to do, especially if you write to a filesystem as well as a db in your view.)