# Django - OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

Tags: mysql, django

Bottom line first: **How do you refresh the MySQL connection in django?**

Following a `MySQL server has gone away` error I found that [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) and other sources ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582506/2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away-in-wsgi-django)) suggest increasing the `wait_timeout` MySQL parameter. To me this seems like a workaround rather than a solution. I'd rather keep a reasonable `wait_timeout` and refresh the connection in the code.

The error:

```
  File "C:\my_proj\db_conduit.py", line 147, in load_some_model
    SomeModel.objects.update()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.6.egg\django\db\models\manager.py", line 177, in update
    return self.get_query_set().update(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.6.egg\django\db\models\query.py", line 469, in update
    transaction.commit(using=self.db)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.6.egg\django\db\transaction.py", line 142, in commit
    connection.commit()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.6.egg\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 201, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.6.egg\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 46, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

Setup: Django 1.3.0 , MySQL 5.5.14 , innodb 1.1.8 , Python 2.6.6, Win7 64bit

Answer (score 10):

The idea of the solution is clear: reconnect to mysql if the current connection is broken.

Please check this out:

```py
def make_sure_mysql_usable():
    from django.db import connection, connections
    # mysql is lazily connected to in django.
    # connection.connection is None means
    # you have not connected to mysql before
    if connection.connection and not connection.is_usable():
        # destroy the default mysql connection
        # after this line, when you use ORM methods
        # django will reconnect to the default mysql
        del connections._connections.default
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Deleting the connection object will cause it to be re-created the next time a Django query is run, so running this function before a query should ensure that the connection is refreshed.   Additionally, if you want to delete the database using a string name (if you have more than one database configured) you can use "del connections._connections.__dict__['default']".

Answer (score 6):

having the same issue.
I need idea how to check connection state for MySQLdb connection in django.
i guess it can be achieved by

```
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
catch OperationalError:
    reconnect
```

is anybody have a better idea?

**UPDATE**

my decision

```
self.connection.stat()
if self.connection.errno()!=0:
```

check state of mysqldb connection if error recreate connection

**UPDATE AGAIN**

you also need to serve case if connection is close

```
if self.connection.open:
    self.connection.stat()
```

refresh connection is just recreating it

```
    db_settings = settings.DATABASES['mysql_db']
    try:
        self.connection = MySQLdb.connect(host=db_settings['HOST'],port=int(db_settings['PORT']),db=db_settings['NAME'],user=db_settings['USER'],passwd=db_settings['PASSWORD'])
    except MySQLdb.OperationalError, e:
        self.connection = None
```

Comment: How do you recreate the connection?

Answer (score 2):

Since Django 1.6, you can use

```
import django.db

django.db.close_old_connections()
```

This does basically the same thing as adamsmith's answer except that it handles multiple databases and also honors the `CONN_MAX_AGE` setting.  Django calls `close_old_connections()` automatically before and after each request, so you normally don't have to worry about it unless you have some long-running code outside of the normal request/response cycle.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason that leads to this exception is mostly due to client ideal longer than `wait_timeout` on mysql server.

In order to prevent that kind of error, `django` supports an option named `CONN_MAX_AGE` which allow django to recreate new connection if old connections are ideal too long.
So you should make sure that `CONN_MAX_AGE` value is smaller than `wait_timout` value.

One important thing is that, `django` with `wsgi` handles checking `CONN_MAX_AGE` every requests by calling `close_old_connections`. So you mainly don't need to care about that. However if you are using `django` in standard alone application, there is no trigger to run that function. So you have to call it manually. So let call `close_old_connections` in your code base.

Note: `close_old_connections` will keep old connections if they're not expired yet. Your connections are still reused in case of high frequency query.

Answer (score 0):

This way can also close the idle connections and make things good.

So before you need to make a query after a long time, running the below lines will work:

```
from django.db import close_old_connections

# To prevent the error if possible.
close_old_connections()
# Then the following sentence should be always ok.
YourModel.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need Django to **auto-refresh database connection** (for Django >= 4.1) you can enable [persistent connections](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#persistent-database-connections) with [health-checks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#conn-max-age)

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS': True,
       'CONN_MAX_AGE': 60,  # <= Mysql `interactive_timeout`/`wait_timeout`  
   }
}
```

As result for each db request Django will ping database to check "if connection is alive" (DatabaseWrapper.is_usable) and restart connection if needed