# work-around for (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')?

Tags: mysql, django, exception

This question is my exact issue

[Django - OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835272/django-operationalerror-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

An aparent work-around to this otherwise unresolved problem is to increase the [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) for the execution

**Background**

I have a celery task which runs at a specific time once a day. Initially it was working fine but from last week i have started getting :

> Exception_ocoured_: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during
>   query')

This celery task simply fetches some details from db, max of 4000 rows and mails to the end user.

**Question :**

Is there any way to increase this timeout *only for the specific celery task* which is facing this issue in django environment, as i don't want to disturb the native setup?

I am looking for a *django*ish solution whose lifetime is only as long as this celery task executes.

For eg :

```
@task
def doSomething():
    try:
       set_timeout_for_mysql = 20000 # <== main agenda for this question
       # OR
       ping_resp = somehow_test_mysql_con()
       while(ping_resp == False):
          keep trying to connect or create new connection
       # do_operations 
    except Exception, e:
       # log exception
```

**Spec :**

```
In [18]: django.VERSION
Out[18]: (1, 7, 7, 'final', 0)
```

and

```
django-celery==3.0.21
```

**PS :**
Any other workaround will do if someone has resolved this without disturbing the core setup!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from django.db import close_old_connections

...
close_old_connections()
...  # do some db jobs, it will reconnect db
```

Good Luck

Comment: yeah...m late i know!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the wait_timeout for each Session (Connection)

```
set wait_timeout=10000;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
```

but, are you sure that the error is from the wait_timeout. a other solution is the max_allowed_packet. You can increase it to see if this the Problem.

Comment: `max_allowed_packet` and this `set wait_timeout`,not sure if i can i directly mention this in my celery `def` or does it need a separate implementation?