# How to prevent MySQL timeout in a Django based deamon app?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-1.7

I wrote a basic FTP Server with pyftpdlib using Django for user management. I wrongly assumed that Django would take care of the db connection and just reconnect automatically after it times out.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify: This is not a Django web service but a deamon that runs on the server only using Django for the easy db interface. I do this because the website that puts the data into the db does it using django. So I thought it might be easy to do that on the deamon side, too, instead of writing my own queries.

Now every few hours I get this:

```
OperationalError(2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

This mostly comes up when nobody is using the server over night - so there seemes to be a db timeout - and then somebody logs in in the morning which causes the FTP service to query the db for password and username using the Django model.

Now how can I make sure that the connection is not gone? Is there any try / except combination to easily check if the connection is still alive and if not just reconnect?

Here is how I did it. In short I store django.contrib.auth.User in self.auth of my FTP class and then whenever I need to check I just ask self.auth.models.Users for validation. Again I assumed if there was a timeout django would take care of it.

Is there anything I can do to make django check and reconnect? Or how can I change my code to prevent that from happening?

```
class DjangoMysqlConnector:
  def __init__(self,SystemLogger=False, BASIC_CONFIG=False):
    self.queue = Queue.Queue()
    self.lock = threading.Lock()

    sys.path.append("/home/user/git/apps")

    if not BASIC_CONFIG:
      sys.path.append("/home/user/django/bildverteiler_project")
      os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "bildverteiler_project.settings")
    else:
      sys.path.append(BASIC_CONFIG["project_path"])
      os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", os.path.basename(BASIC_CONFIG["project_path"])+".settings")

    django.setup()

    import bildverteiler
    from django.contrib import auth
    self.auth = auth

class CustomDummyAuthorizer(DummyAuthorizer):
  def __init__(self,user_query,*args,**kwargs):
    super(CustomDummyAuthorizer,self).__init__()
    self.user_query = user_query

  def validate_authentication(self, username, password, arg):
    try:
      user_obj = self.user_query.objects.get(username=username)
    except:
      print "user does not exist: "+str(sys.exc_info())
      raise AuthenticationFailed("failed")
    else:
      if not self.has_user(username):
        try:
          os.makedirs("/home/user/git/verteilerCore2/default_basedir/in/"+str(user_obj.pk))
        except OSError:
          pass
        self.add_user(user_obj.username, 'xxx', "/home/user/git/verteilerCore2/default_basedir/in/"+str(user_obj.pk), perm='elradfmwM')
    if user_obj.check_password(password):
      print "password geht"
      return None
    else:
      print "password wrong"
      raise AuthenticationFailed("failed")


class FtpThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, user_query):
    self.user_query = user_query
    self.killswitch = 0
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.setDaemon(True)
  def run(self,*args,**kwargs):
    authorizer = CustomDummyAuthorizer(self.user_query)
    handler = FTPHandler
    handler.authorizer = authorizer

    logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/log/verteiler_ftp.log', level=logging.WARN)
    handler.banner = "pyftpdlib based ftpd ready."

    address = ('', 21)
    self.server = FTPServer(address, handler)

    self.server.max_cons = 256
    self.server.max_cons_per_ip = 30

    self.server.serve_forever()

  def stop(self):
    self.server.close_all()
```

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to resolve the issue somehow?

Comment: seems like a variant of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32765696/2012422